# PYMC - 95% credible intervals

Tags: python, pymc

(nb. just posted this on the google group, but it says it is now deprecated)

I have some code which fits about 12 model parameters to a series of datasets. The results from the pymc code appear fine and consistent with an identical version of the code I have which uses the lmfit package, i.e. non-linear least squares. One concern I do have is that the 95% credible intervals are to my mind tiny and this suggests to me there is an error somewhere. The standard errors from the other fitting script are reasonable in size and the function is complex enough to suggest such unique minima are unlikely. Could this be a consequence of how I am sampling the data? I am carrying out 100,000 iterations, burning 50,000 and thinning by a factor of 10.

My code is:

https://github.com/mdekauwe/FitFarquharModel/blob/master/fit_farquhar_model/fit_dummy_pymc.py

I can try and upload a sample driving file if that helps, but perhaps I have done something obviously stupid?

When I say tiny here is an example:

[lmfit] Vcmax25_1 = 16.55232485 +/- 1.22831709 (Std.err)

[pymc]  Vcmax25_1 = 19.5718912 [19.57150052, 19.57232205] (95% HPD)

Many thanks,

Martin

ps. I have added an example file should anyone want to test it. The bottom of that script has the necessary links...(of course one would need to download the files from the examples directory)

my guess is the sampler must get stuck so I will try and look in more detail at the traces.